# Get keys of object in order?

Tags: javascript, json

Can we get keys of a `JSON` in the same order it was received?

`Object.keys(company).length` works, but I need confirmation if it will always work.

```
{
  "hello":"world",
  "welcome":"back",
  "1":"2"
}
```

How can we get keys in the same order?

```
["hello","welcome","1"]
```

Comment: From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys): _The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, **in the same order** as we get with a normal loop_.

Comment: There is no such global guarantee. Neither JS objects (per ECMAScript specs) nor JSON guarantees key order - insert or otherwise. JSON itself expresses your forbids/excludes ordering assumptions.

Comment: @Shirersz The flaw in that statement is the incorrect assumption that the “normal loop” has a guaranteed order of key iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off storing your data in a Map to ensure insertion order and entry retrieval.

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Still ‘excludes’ key ordering from JSON (or even objects creating said Maps) and parsing of such.

Comment: You can't serialize a map. This is not an answer to the question.